# Issues with Windows 10 Sleeping - USB Suspend Issues

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

My Windows 10 desktop computer won't go into sleep mode automatically after 10 minutes like I have it set to in the power settings.  It will go into sleep manually if I choose it from the Start/Power menu.  But something wakes it up shortly after and again won't automatically go to sleep.

I have been reading posts/articles and learned to run powercfg/energy and get the report to tell me what is preventing sleeping.  In my case it all appears to be related to USB:

[image: powercfg.jpg]

I went into the "Power Options" "Advanced settings" and ensured that the "USB selective suspend setting" was set to  enabled.

Then I went into my Device Manager to check if the devices listed in the report.  Some like the "Generic USB Hub" have a "Power Management" tab and I checked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" box.  But most devices on the list, like my external hard drive and scanner don't have this option.

I'm not even sure that this option is related to sleeping.  In either case, when I run the powercfg/energy report, I get the same results.

Hoping somebody can help me configure my computer so it goes to sleep as it's supposed to.

Comment: Check in BIOS that any "Wake On ..." is disabled. Restart, update BIOS and Power Driver, restart again and test.

Comment: @John I checked my BIOS and there was no "Wake on" or something similar in any of the menus.  I don't think it's BIOS related as I can manually set it to sleep, it just doesn't happen when the computer has been idle.

Comment: My system was updated a couple days ago and now it goes to sleep as expected.  When I run powercfg/energy now, I still get the same errors.  So, I guess they weren't related to the not sleeping problem.

Comment: I am not clear. You updated as suggested, then said it goes to sleep as expected.  But still gives errors.

Comment: @John It was a regular Windows update, not BIOS.

Comment: Try updating BIOS to a newer version to see if that helps